# How does Java primitive wrapper classes support additional methods in Groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I come from the Java background and now I'm learning Groovy. The following code is a valid Groovy code.

```
def val=1
println val.getClass() //will print java.lang.Integer
def ans=3.intdiv(2)    //performs integer division
```

I wonder, how does the Groovy add such method as `intdiv` to the final `java.lang.Integer` class? There are a lot of other such methods, like `times`, `upto`, `downto`, `step`, and so on. Those methods are added to the Java class that is final. How is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Those methods you mentioned are called **Default Groovy Methods** and most of them are implemented in the [`org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java) class. A method like `intdiv` is not added to the final `Integer` class, but instead, it is implemented for any `Number` class in the default Groovy methods. Now, when Groovy compiler compiles Groovy code to the bytecode, it detects something like `2.intdiv(3)` and it replaces this expression with the equivalent of something like `DefaultGroovyMethods.intdiv(2,3)`.

To make this illustration even more clear, take a look at the following Groovy class:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class SomeClass {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def val=1
        println val.getClass()
        def ans = 3.intdiv(2)
        println ans
    }
}
```

When you compile it to `SomeClass.class` file and then decompile it to Java (e.g. by opening such file in the IntelliJ IDEA), you will see the following Java class equivalent:

```java
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import groovy.transform.Generated;
import groovy.transform.Internal;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation;

public class SomeClass implements GroovyObject {
    @Generated
    public SomeClass() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int val = 2;
        int some = DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(DefaultGroovyMethods.intdiv(Integer.valueOf(val), 3));
        DefaultGroovyMethods.println(SomeClass.class, some);
        Object var10000 = null;
    }

    @Generated
    @Internal
    public MetaClass getMetaClass() {
        MetaClass var10000 = this.metaClass;
        if (var10000 != null) {
            return var10000;
        } else {
            this.metaClass = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
            return this.metaClass;
        }
    }

    @Generated
    @Internal
    public void setMetaClass(MetaClass var1) {
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }
}
```

You can see that

```
def ans = 3.intdiv(2)
```

becomes

```
int some = DefaultTypeTransformation.intUnbox(DefaultGroovyMethods.intdiv(Integer.valueOf(val), 3));
```

There is no magic, it is just Groovy compiler that knows how to do such transformations on the abstract-syntax tree.